# Have a regex that matches either one group or other group characters, same on both sides

Tags: regex

I have two different windows event logs, i want to capture only the domain name from event logs.

Event Log1:

> hostname02.testdomain1.com    MSWinEventLog

Event Log2:

> <46>Nov 10 12:47:31 hostname01.testdomain2.com MSWinEventLog

I want to match the domain name like `testdomain1.com` or `testdomain2.com`

Right now, I have this: this one capture only my Event Log2 but not Event Log1.

```
[A-z]{3}[ ]{1,2}\d{1,2}\s\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\:\d{1,2}\s[a-zA-Z0-9]*.(\w.*)\sMS
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a [positive lookahead](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

[`\w+\.\w+(?=\sMSWinEventLog)`](https://regex101.com/r/YFUA3a/1)

Matches `testdomain1.com` or `testdomain2.com`

Answer (score 2):

You could use

```
\w+(?:\.\w+)+(?=\s*MSWinEventLog)
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/uNoor8/1/).

Answer (score 1):

The intent is a little bit unclear, but here is a regexp that might work for you:

```
[^.]+\.([\w.]+\.com)\s*MS
```

This matches anything other than `.` until it sees a `.`, and then captures the domain name. See it in action here: https://regex101.com/r/cuAIaU/1/

Comment: You have to escape the dot.

Comment: use this: `[^.]+.([\w.]+\.com)\s*MS`. You need to create a character class capturing words and `.`